# What is the difference between setting a property on app.locals and calling app.set()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm in the process of learning Express - and thinking of the best place to save config style data. Options available are either in app.locals or app.set (settings)... so:

```
app.locals({ config: {
    name: 'My App',
    domain: 'myapp.com',
    viewPath: __dirname+'/views',
    viewEngine: 'jade'
    port: 3000
} });

app.set('view engine', app.locals.config.viewEngine || 'jade');
```

This would also allow me to use the following in my views:

```
<title>#{config.name}</title> // <title>My App</title>
```

Or the alternative is to use app.set like so:

```
app.set('name', 'My App');
app.set('domain', 'myapp.com');
```

... and then use this in the view:

```
<title>#{settings.name}</title>
```

I know both methods work, but I'm struggling to determine which is the better method to use. At the moment I'm leaning towards using app.locals, with the extra 'app' namespace as I believe there would be less chance of conflicts with future updates and other modules if using app.set.

Comment: I've updated this with the right answer please evaluate it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20653926/124486

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wow, all of the answers are wrong, so let me give it a try. Despite what others say **assinging to the app.local argument is different from using app.set()**. Watch,

```
app.js
  app.locals.foo = 'bar';
  app.set('baz', 'quz');  


index.jade
  block content                            
    dl                                     
      dt app.locals.foo = 'bar';            
      dd \#{settings.foo} = #{settings.foo}
      dd \#{foo} = #{foo}                  

      dt app.set('baz', 'quz')             
      dd \#{settings.baz} = #{settings.baz}
      dd \#{baz} = #{baz}
```

If you ran this code, what you would see is,

```
app.locals.foo = 'bar';
  #{settings.foo} =
  #{foo} = bar
app.set('baz', 'quz')
  #{settings.baz} = quz
  #{baz} =
```

The reason for this is setting [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) sets attributes of the object that the view uses as its environment; what the view will read from without qualification. Conversely, [app.set](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set) sets attributes on `app.locals.settings`. You can verify this if you clobber `app.locals.settings` in the above with `app.locals.settings = {}`, which will make `#{settings.baz}` undefined.

**So which do you use? If it's not an app setting based on the response (`res.set`) or global configuration (`app.set`), use the direct write to `app.locals`.**

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand when to use which. What do you mean by "an app setting based on the response (res.set) or global configuration (app.set)"?

Answer (score 4):

All properties of `app.locals` are available in templates. Using `app.set` assigns properties to `app.locals.settings`, which is used for global application settings and is inherited by mounted applications. For example:

```
var app1 = express(),
    app2 = express();

app1.set('inheritable', 'foo');
app1.locals.notInheritable = 'bar';

app1.use('/mount', app2);

app2.get('inheritable') === 'foo'; // true
app2.locals.notInheritable === 'bar'; // false
```

So it's really a question of preference and whether or not you're mounting applications.

Answer (score 2):

The express [api reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) says :

> By default Express exposes only a single app-level local variable,
>   settings.

and either way is ok:

```
app.locals.title = 'My App';

app.set('title', 'My App');
// use settings.title in a view
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, [see my answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20653926/124486).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people indeed use locals instead of app.set so my advice is to use that.