# how to deal with dynamically allocated port in api endpoint in react app?

Tags: reactjs, api, express, dynamic, port

I am writing an react application. It works with a api endpoint running at a particular port. My server side application requires that I provide a random free port at runtime for which I use the getport node module. 
But how do i communicate this to single page react app which is already built where it deals with a api endpoints from a particular port like localhost:3000

Answer (score 1):

You can use Environment variables to template your Port number. So despite your single page app being compiled, your server will pass on env variables to your application.

Comment: Any examples links?

Comment: @uman - Assuming you are using a node.js server, refer to this example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656326/how-to-set-port-for-express-server-dynamically/42705038

Comment: I have already implemented dynamic port allocation on the server side. But the problem is the client side. the port number is random and keeps changing in my application and there are many instances of the server running at the same time at different ports.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your react app in an express server that can proxy your api requests.The servers can register their ***ip:port*** to this server and using that data the express server can route the requests.

When you start your instances of server side application let them register themselves to this running server using a special endpoint **/reg**. You can proxy all your api requests to your server app when they are routed through **/api**.

**Sample Code:**

```js
import express from 'express';
import proxy from 'express-http-proxy';

const port = "80";
const app = express();
const serverAddressList = [];

function getHost() {
    //logic to select ip from serverAddressList.Can do load balancing here
    return serverAddressList[0];
}

app.get('/reg', (req, res, next) => {
    const serverAddress = req.query.address;
    serverAddressList.push(serverAddress);
});

app.use('/api', proxy(getHost, {
    memoizeHost: false
}));

app.use('/', express.static(REACT_GENERATED_CODE_LOCATION));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    const location = path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../${REACT_GENERATED_CODE_LOCATION}/index.html`);
    res.sendFile(location);
});

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```