# Gulp bundle and package-solution not working in Sharepoint Framework using gulp-nodemon

Tags: reactjs, express, sharepoint, gulp, spfx

When trying to bundle and package-solution in gulp (using SharePoint Framework and express.js) to create a web part these functions don't work. gulp bundle --ship just does not end as I am using gulp-nodemon as a server for express and it is constantly 'Listening on port 5000'.

It is giving me the below error when trying to package-solution --ship 'Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found in 'C:\SPFX Projects.../manifests'. Ensure a build has completed successfully'. Obviously because the gulp bundle wasn't able to complete.

So when running gulp bundle --ship it does not end saying it's still 'Listening on port 5000'. How do I get around this so I can bundle and package my solution? Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
"use strict";

const build = require("@microsoft/sp-build-web");
const gulp = require("gulp");
const nodemon = require("gulp-nodemon");

build.addSuppression(
  `Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`
);

var getTasks = build.rig.getTasks;
build.rig.getTasks = function () {
  var result = getTasks.call(build.rig);

  result.set("serve", result.get("serve-deprecated"));

  return result;
};

/* fast-serve */
const { addFastServe } = require("spfx-fast-serve-helpers");
addFastServe(build);
/* end of fast-serve */

let serverSubTask = build.subTask(
  "server",
  function (gulp, buildOptions, done) {
    nodemon({
      script: "server.js",
      ext: "js html",
      env: { NODE_ENV: "development" },
      done: done,
    });
  }
);

build.rig.addPostBuildTask(serverSubTask);

build.initialize(require("gulp"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Port conflict:
You mentioned that you are using gulp-nodemon as the express server and it is listening on port 5000. This can cause conflicts with the gulp bundle --ship command since it needs to use the same port. You can try changing the port of the express server, for example to use a free port.

Here is link for your reference:
[How to set port for express server dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656326/how-to-set-port-for-express-server-dynamically)